# TFS explorer you're accessing sensitive info, you need to verify your password

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2017, tortoisegit, team-explorer

I am trying to do syn on git repo using visual studio 2017 team explorer but keep getting password prompt like this

[image]

even though I am entering the correct password.

**Enter password**

```
Because you're accessing sensitive info, you need to verify your password.

Password


Forgot my password 

Sign in with a different Microsoft account
```

same credentials are working different computer. It was working fine until I updated visual studio 2017 to latest version 15.7.3. I tried to reset password, reinstalled git, reset VS settings. I get same issue if i try to do git pull using tortoise git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\TortoiseGit\cache64 file and issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using VSTS, based on your description it should be related to the `Security info & security codes` of your Microsoft Account.

So, you can try to [manage/update/remove the security info](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/12428/microsoft-account-security-info-and-security-codes) for your Microsoft Account, then check if that works for you.

Reference the related thread here : https://forums.techguy.org/threads/hotmail-security-code.1105087/